# how to make a RTL Menu in angular

Tags: html, angular

Hi i am Learning Angular 
I just Made an angular Panel But I want It To Be Rtl But I do not Know How To do That 
This Is My Panel
[image: 1]

this Is My Html Code

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <button mat-icon-button >
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <span> Admin Panel </span>

        <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
            <ul fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
                <li>
                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This Is My css

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?
[image]

Code:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row fxLayout="row-reverse">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span> Admin Panel </span>
        <span fxFlex="1 1"></span>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav position="end">
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Using the `fxLayout="row-reverse"`-property in your `<mat-toolbar-row>`

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kgnvebakmpj

fyi if you only have one toolbar row, you can leave out the `<mat-toolbar-row>`.

Comment: what about menu?

Comment: @nazanintahmaseb updated my answer. Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kgnvebakmpj

Comment: can you please chrck out my new question and help me if you can?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909626/how-to-make-a-rtl-profile-in-angular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912660/how-to-make-rtl-profile-in-angular